# Will removing background give me better image classification accuracy?

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I'm building an vehicle damage detection model using computer vision. I'm reduced the problem to image classification with classes being glass shatter, dent, headlight damage, taillight damage for now. I have samples belong to each class.

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/An1GN.png)

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0tUO.jpg)

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIFI0.jpg)

I would like to know, will removing the background of the samples and feeding it to the image classification model give me better accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: it won't.

Reason: a classifier will only activate (focus, attend) at specific parts of query image and ignore other un-related parts. This is called the heatmap. [image] . The heatmap will later be used for classification or detection, segmentation, etc. 
You can google for "convnet visualization" and try by yourself. it will be great studying experience.